# jquery autocomplete pass one variable to second autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have 2 auto completes on one page that search an sql databases and display results into input fields. The fist auto complete works great. The second one requires the client_id to be passed through because it searches the sql based on the client id of the first search. Also, I would like the second auto complete to display all results as soon as the user clicks inside the box. Here is my code.

```
$( "#client_name" ).autocomplete(
{
    source:'ls_billto_client_name.php',
    minLength: 0,
    select: function(event, ui){
       $("#client_id").val(ui.item.client_id)
       $("#client_name").val(ui.item.label)
       $("#shipto_id").val(ui.item.client_default_shipto_id)
       $('#shipto_name').prop('disabled', false);
    }
})

$( "#shipto_name" ).autocomplete(
{
    source: 'ls_shipto_locations.php?client_id='+ $("#client_id").val(),
    minLength: 0,
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#shipto_id").val(ui.item.shipto_id)
        $("#shipto_name").val(ui.item.label)
        $("#shipto_street").val(ui.item.shipto_street)
        $("#shipto_city").val(ui.item.shipto_city)
        $("#shipto_stateprov").val(ui.item.shipto_stateprov)
        $("#shipto_country").val(ui.item.shipto_country)
        $("#shipto_postalzip").val(ui.item.shipto_postalzip)
        $("#shipto_phone").val(ui.item.shipto_phone)
        $("#shipto_fax").val(ui.item.shipto_fax)
        $("#shipto_website").val(ui.item.shipto_website)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you instantiate the `autocomplete` on `$('#shipto_name')`, it's not dynamic. it's taking the value straight away to populate the field, instead, you need to perform an ajax request to the server, which in return will provide you with your results. Once you have those results, you can map them to the response callback provided by the source to create your dropdown.

```
$('#shipto_name').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url:'ls_shipto_locations.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {client_id : request.term},
            success: function(data){
                response($.map(data, function(obj){ //response is the callback
                    //considering obj should be JSON with key:value pairs
                    return{
                        label: obj.key, //key is the literal key of the object returned
                        value: obj.key  //key is the literal key of the object returned
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now shipto will properly look for the client id within that file location. We expect the returned data from the server to be a JSON encoded object that looks like:

```
{label: 'Hello', value: 'World'}
```

You'll notice in the `source:` construct above, we use `request.term` instead of `$('#client_id').val()`, this is much more dynamic. Let's see how we work with the `$('#client_name').autocomplete({ select })` event to pass the data we want over.

```
$('#client_name').autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui){
        //your code
        $('#shipto_name').autocomplete('search', ui.item.client_id);
    }
});
```

By calling autocomplete's search and passing in the term, we're telling it to perform the search. `ui.item.client_id` will now be available as `request_term` in our `$('#shipto_name').autocomplete()`.

This should be the intended functionality you're going for.

Comment: search return..how do i display the results with the ajax request?

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $shiptoname[] = array(
  'shipto_id' => $row['shipto_id'],
  'label' => $row['shipto_name'],
  'shipto_street' => $row['shipto_street'],
  'shipto_city' => $row['shipto_city'],
  'shipto_stateprov' => $row['shipto_stateprov'],
  'shipto_country' => $row['shipto_country'],
  'shipto_postalzip' => $row['shipto_postalzip'],
  'shipto_phone' => $row['shipto_phone'],
  'shipto_fax' => $row['shipto_fax'],
  'shipto_website' => $row['shipto_website']
  );
}

echo json_encode($shiptoname);

Comment: @snowman1686 The array would need to be something like `'label' => $row['whatever'], 'value' => $row['whatever']` then you would json encode it. If you want to use other peices of data, you'll need to use the `._renderItem` method to return a mappable object that you can use to build out your autocomplete list.

Comment: Should have specified. Not displayed in the drop down. when selected it will populate the input fields on the page with the json returned from the sql.